# No module named flask_bcrypt

Tags: python

```
python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskblog import create_app
  File "/home/vguggilam/Downloads/Python/Flask_Blog/12-Error-Pages/flaskblog/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
ImportError: No module named flask_bcrypt
```

Comment: Have you installed `flask_bcrypt`?

Comment: `pip install Flask-Bcrypt`. https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Bcrypt/

Comment: try `from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt` https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 8):

You need to install `flask_bcrypt` as follows:

`pip install flask-bcrypt`

Comment: OK then it is probably permission issue. Can you try `easy_install flask-bcrypt`?

Comment: I tried 

**from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt**

Python still doesn't import it

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a virtual environment like virtualenv or pipenv,  it is highly suggested to install the package outside of the environment, for all python versions:

```
pip install flask-bcrypt && pip3 install flask-bcrypt
```

Then, access your virtual environment, activate it if necessary, and install the package there. In my case I am using pipenv, thus the installation was with:

```
pipenv install flask-bcrypt
```

After doing this I no longer had this import trouble.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways of doing it that I found was this. (Works only if you're using a virtual env, if not, create a VE and install all your requirements first. I'm using virtualenv)

1)(in your virtual environment, after you have installed your dependencies)

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

2. delete the virtualenv folder from your directory completely. in my case, I had named my VE, venv, so I deleted that folder. remember to close any terminals with the VE activated. this can lead to cached data that might alter the result.
3. create and activate VE again.

   pip install virtualenv

(only if you haven't installed it)

```
virtualenv venv
```

your VE can be anything, here I've named it venv

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

works for Windows, for Mac, and Linux, please look up docs on activating venv.
4) re-install all your dependencies. PS: make sure the venv is activated.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

you should be good to go. this method is basically using force but works great for a lot of faulty import errors or dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Install **wheel** it is a requiremnt for **flask_bcrypt**

```
pip install wheel
```

```
pip install flask_bcrypt
```